# Cyclic dependency in module 'Darwin': Darwin -> Medialib -> UIKit -> Darwin

Tags: ios, xcode, darwin

Getting this weird error suddenly. Not sure if Xcode got corrupted.
Anyone know how to fix this errors in Xcode.

Code is clean for sure its working fine other machines, its some issue with Xcode setup or some configuration.

> 'time.h' file not found with  include; use "quotes" instead
>
> Cyclic dependency in module 'Darwin': Darwin -> Medialib -> UIKit -> Darwin
>
> Cyclic dependency in module 'Darwin': Darwin -> Medialib -> UIKit -> Foundation -> CoreFoundation -> Darwin
>
> Could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftShims'

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild?

Answer (score 1):

try to check if you have a src with name time.h that conflicts with system time.h